ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy._core'
I am trying to load a .npy file created on my local PC with np.save() in google colaboratory. However, when I try to open it on Google Colab with np.load() I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy._core'
I am not sure if its an issue related to different numpy versions, numpy version on my pc is 2.0.0 (newest), and numpy version on colab is 1.25
I've already tried to downgrade or upgrade numpy so the version matches in both environments.

Same thing here. Wasn't happening before! Did they make some changes to numpy yesterday?

I had the same issue, I reinstalled Numpy and now it works:
pip3 install numpy
<SNIP>
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-2.0.1

Version is now 2.0.1
